# Mongoose not saving passed field to collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Mongoose schema with the following definition:

```
var mongoose        = require('mongoose');
var accountSchema   = require('./accountSchema.js');   
var orders          = require('./orderSchema.js');

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    truckId: String,
    truckDetails: {
        licensePlate: String,
        model: String,
        make: String
    },
    driver: accountSchema.schema,
    onboard: [orders.schema]
},{
    collection: 'truckMap'
});

truckModel = mongoose.model('truckMapSchema', schema);
```

And an API route which saves a document to my mongodb database:

```
router.post('/api/update/truckmap/',
function(req, res, next) { passport.authenticate('jwt',
function(err, user, info){

    if(err) { return next(err) }
    if(!user) { return res.json({ success: "false" , status: 403, msg: "Authentication failed."})}

    Account.findOne({email: user.local.email}, function(err, docs){
        if(err){ res.send({success: 'false', msg: 'Error occured while trying to find driver.'})}

        if(!docs) { res.send({sucess: 'false', msg: 'Driver not found.'})}
        else {
            var truck = new Truck();

            truck.truckId = req.body.truck_id;
            console.log('licensePlate: ' + req.body.license_plate);

            truck.truckDetails.licencePlate = req.body.license_plate;
            truck.truckDetails.model = req.body.model;
            truck.truckDetails.make = req.body.make;

//                truck.driver = driver;
            truck.onboard = [];

            truck.save();
            res.send({success: true, msg: "truckmap updated"})
        }
    });

    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Now when I pass the following information using a POST request:

```
header - 
    Authorization: <jwt token>

body - 
    email: admin@cc.com
    truck_id: 1
    license_plate: 1234a
    model: asdf
    make: qwer
```

It creates a document in my collection, however the licensePlate field under truckDetails is missing:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5872a113e41d0076628ddf74"),
    "truckId" : "1",
    "onboard" : [ ],
    "truckDetails" : {
        "make" : "qewr",
        "model" : "asdf"
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Above in the route function, I logged the value of `req.body.license_plate` which outputs the correct value.

I figured it could be an embedded document issue, however `model` and `make` are stored without any hassle.

Not sure how to go forward.

Comment: There is typing mistake of `s` in licensePlate in your schema design. It should be `licencePlate` instead of `licensePlate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be minor typo in your code.

**truckMap schema**

```
truckDetails: {
    licensePlate: String, // notice the `s`
    model: String,
    make: String
},
```

**POST request**

```
header - 
    Authorization: <jwt token>

body - 
    email: admin@cc.com
    truck_id: 1
    license_plate: 1234a  // `s` here too
    model: asdf
    make: qwer
```

Though you are console logging your value, it has correct spelling

```
console.log('licensePlate: ' + req.body.license_plate); // `s` here too
```

but when saving you are using `c` instead of `s`

```
truck.truckDetails.licencePlate = req.body.license_plate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixed types don't do change tracking without help in Mongoose.  Add in:

```
truck.markModified('truckDetails');
```

prior to saving.